# Store uploaded images on Network using Ip address in c#

Tags: c#, file, upload

I am working on uploading a file from MVC and I want to store the uploaded images on the network or any other system,I have IP address of that system,

Can anyone help me to find out where I am making mistake or is there some other way to store image on certain IP address.

```
I am using this code to save image on another machine with IP address

    public ActionResult Test(string ENROLLIMAGE)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ENROLLIMAGE))
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ENROLLIMAGE"];
            Guid ImageId = Guid.NewGuid();
           var filename = ImageId.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
           file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("\\\\192.168.11.113\\D:\\UploadedFiles" +     filename));
           Uri addy = new Uri("\\\\192.168.11.113\\D:\\UploadedFiles" + filename);


        }
        return View();
    }
```

Kindly help !!!!
It is giving me error while I am trying to upload that "The given path's format is not supported."

Thanks

Comment: I suggest trying to access the path using windows explorer or winkey+R. Your share name is probably "D$" and not "D:". I also suggest using "@" before the path string to reduce the number of "\" charachters.

Comment: Hi argaz ,I already tried with giving path with @"192.168.11.113\D:\UploadedFiles" but it did not work,is there any way to perform this

Comment: Try D$, also like I said in the first comment you can save time and troubleshoot better by trying to access the shared folder with windows explorer or winkey+R, just put the path there and press enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a drive specification like `D:` in an UNC path. What you should do is make a network share of the `UploadedFiles` folder on the remote machine, and use `file.SaveAs("\\\\192.168.11.113\\UploadedFiles\\" + filename);`

`D:` is not allowed in an UNC path, and will give you the error.

So, either use `file.SaveAs("\\\\192.168.11.113\\<ShareNameHere>\\" + filename)`, or use `file.SaveAs("\\\\192.168.11.113\\D$\\UploadedFiles\\" + filename)` if you have administrative privileges on the target machine.

Comment: HI Stephen Thanks for you reply,can you please describe it little more so that I can get an idea how to do it.

Comment: On the target machine, go to the UploadedFiles folder, and share that folder. (right-click=>properties, sharing tab).

Comment: Hi Stephen,I already shared whole drive and folder and make them public.

Comment: Then use the sharename in your SaveSs command, or, like argaz said, use 'D$' instead of 'D:'.

Comment: Ok I used "D$' instead of "D" but still having the same issue and it is giving me error The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: meh... that's what I get for copy/pasting. Do not use Server.MapPath for an UNC path. I corrected my answer.